# QGIS 2.0.1.3 (Dufour) and 2..2.0.1 (Valmiera) 64 Bit versions: uninstall not completely possible, crashes at exit

Tags: qgis, windows-7

haven't tried the stackexchange page before, but since I can't find information on this problem: I can't completely uninstall QGIS, I want to do a complete, clean reinstall, but whenever I start the installer after having uninstalled QGIS it shows:

> QGIS Dufour or QGIS Valmiera already installed

So it seems the uninstall doesn't work properly.

I'm working on a *Fujitsu Esprimo with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz (8 CPUs), ~3.4GHz, 32768MB RAM, Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1*.

I've recently tried installing OSGEO4W in addition to QGIS. Can this be the problem? Another thing that kept happening with all my QGIS installation from 2.0 upwards (I have only the newest one installed currently, 2.2 Valmiera) is crashes at exit ("QGIS.bin has stopped working). I'm having no other problems with it though.

Could you give me instructions on how to completely remove the program and do a clean reinstall? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by removing the reg key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\QGIS Valmiera".  You can then reinstall the 64bit version.

Comment: Before doing this, remember to backup the registry!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to completely remove QGIS:

- `Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Functions` to uninstall the software
- Delete the remaining installed folder under

  `C:\Programs\` (for Standalone 64bit),
    `C:\Programs (86)\` (for Standalone 32bit), 
    `C:\OSGe04W` or
    `C:\OSGeo4W64`
- Remove the `.qgis2` path from your `C:\user\...` folder
- start `regedit`, search and remove all entries containing QGIS

... and try the 32bit version, it has fewer installation bugs.

Answer (score -2):

QGIS Dufour or QGIS Valmiera already installed
Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Functions

Comment: The solution suggested above by dbarkey works, I can confirm this. You need to delete the registry key he specified after deinstallation of the program. Somehow this error occurs only in the 64bit version, it doesn't occur in 32bit QGIS. It's still present in QGIS Chugiak (2.4.0), haven't tried the newest one (2.6.0 "Brighton") yet.